# Ember controller length test not functioning as intended

Tags: ember.js

I've inherited a project using Ember 1.0 and I'm new to Ember. There's an issue in the code where the length test is not functioning as intended.

```
Chat.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    messageAdded: function(m) {
        if (this.get('length') > 0) {
            $('#chat').removeClass('empty-of-messages');
            $(document).trigger('chat_on');
        }
    }.observes('content.@each')
});
```

When messageAdded fires, the length is always one less than what's expected. Why is this?

I can add other pieces of the code if it's helpful. Please let me know generally what you'd be looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You probably don't want to be using the `ArrayController` anymore as it's deprecated.

Comment: Have you tried `get('content.length')`?

Comment: @albertjan I had not, but it does work.

Comment: Think about upgrading to Ember 2.x since it's really different from 1.0 and almost everything from 1.0 is deprecated.